# swift simple view app

Tags: ios, swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController
{
  @IBOutlet weak var simpleTextField: UITextField!
  @IBOutlet weak var simpleLabel: UILabel!

  @IBAction func changeLabel(sender: AnyObject)
  {
    simpleLabel.text = "salam, " + simpleTextField.text + "!";
  }

}
```

I am a new swift learner and I'm trying to launch a simple app. I drag a label to storyboard. At first when I run the app it shows **signal SIGABRT error**. I cant solve the problem and I rewrite the code then  when I try to run the app I have a problem. and when I run the app it show error breakpoint 1.5 its about

how can fix it?
thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please finish off your post - in particular please show us exactly what the error is. Without that information, nobody will be able to help you

Comment: Check to see if you properly connected Actions and Outlets to the view controller from Interface Builder. Delete invalid connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if all **IBOutlet** and **IBAction** are connected to their respective code.And also change the your IBAction code to this following

```
 @IBAction func changeLabel(sender: AnyObject) {
    simpleLabel.text = "salam \(simpleTextField.text) !"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced that before.
Check @IBOutlet and @IBAction in storyboard.

[image]

Watch out for following point

・Not double connection.

・Not forget to delete connection that is not used.

That's all.